# Golang derefencing function return value

Tags: go

I'm messing with the flag library, and found that this code does not work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "flag"
)

var recursive bool

func init() {
    recursive = *flag.Bool("r", false, "Search recursively")
}
func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Printf("Recursive: %t \n\n", recursive)

    flag.PrintDefaults()

}
```

But this does (I commented the three lines I changed):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "flag"
)

var recursive *bool   //Changed to pointer type

func init() {
    recursive = flag.Bool("r", false, "Search recursively") //Changed to not dereference function
}
func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Printf("Recursive: %t \n\n", *recursive)  //Changed to dereference variable

    flag.PrintDefaults()

}
```

Why does this behave like this?  Are functions not allowed to be dereferenced in Golang, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks!! Should I edit it, or would that be considered bad form since it would make your comment and the top answer appear wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because when you call `flag.Bool()`, it does not yet parse the command line arguments, it just defines a named flag and initializes it with the default value (which is `false` as you specified it).

Command line arguments are only parsed when you call `flag.Parse()`. If you use `recursive bool`, in the `init()` function the default `false` will be assigned to it. The `flag` package does not know about your `recursive` variable, so later when you call `flag.Parse()`, its value will not/ cannot be changed.

`flag.Bool()` returns a pointer to a `bool` variable which the `flag` package knows about, and later when you call `flag.Parse()` the pointed `bool` variable will be properly updated, so when you print the pointed valued after `flag.Bool()`, it will be the updated value which will be set based on your command line arguments.

### Alternative: Register your variable

So you **must** store and use the pointer returned by `flag.Bool()` else you will only see the default value. **Or** you can let the `flag` package know about your `recursive` variable: you can tell the `flag` package that you what it to store the result into *your* `recursive` variable by telling this with the `flag.BoolVar()` function:

```
flag.BoolVar(&recursive, "r", false, "Search recursively")
```

Note that in this case there is no return value, becase you explicitly provided a pointer to a `bool` which you want the `flag` package to store the result to.